# Puppet string interpolation with function call and a variable as parameter

Tags: puppet, syntax

Trying to construct a string.

I can do:

`"Blah blah ${::osfamily} blah blah"`

`"Blah blah ${$::osfamily} blah blah"`

But whats the syntax to call a function with a variable as parameter and have string interpolation work?

None of the following worked:

`"Blah blah ${downcase($::osfamily)} blah blah"`

`"Blah blah ${downcase($osfamily)} blah blah"`

`"Blah blah ${downcase(::osfamily)} blah blah"`

`"Blah blah ${$downcase(osfamily)} blah blah"`

`"Blah blah ${$downcase($osfamily)} blah blah"`
and so on.

All I get is:
`Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at '('; expected ')'`

Is that even possible in Puppet language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible.  Puppet's language is a little ideosyncratic, in that many things you'd think would work just... don't.  You'll need to assign the return value from the function to a variable, then interpolate that variable into the string, like this:

```
$downcased_osfamily = downcase($::osfamily)
"Blah blah ${downcased_osfamily} blah blah"
```

Of course, a string by itself isn't any use, so presumably you're assigning that string to a variable of its own, or using it as the value for a resource attribute.

Comment: OMG. For reeeealllz?

Comment: For reeeeeeealllz.  You'll bump into a bunch of other things like this with functions in Puppet -- like no nesting calls (you can't `downcase(template("something"))`, for example).  Puppet's language wasn't "designed", it was "spawned".

Comment: I would like to have a word with the "spawner(s)".... sigh.

Comment: That would be Luke Kanies.  Nice guy, and a good demonstration of why us sysadmins shouldn't try to become application developers.  <grin>

Answer (score 7):

It *wasn't* possible, but it is now. The following works using your example:

```
notice("Blah blah ${downcase($::osfamily)} blah blah")
```

This was tested on Puppet 4.10.x, it's documented as far back as 4.6: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.6/lang_data_string.html#interpolation

Comment: Worked for me with puppet-master 4.8.2 and puppet (client) 3.8.5 .  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

further to bogit's answer you are also able to use the following syntax

```
puppet apply -e 'notice("Blah blah ${::osfamily.downcase} blah blah")'
```

you may also want to use the newer facts hash as well

```
puppet apply -e 'notice("Blah blah ${facts['os']['family'].downcase} blah blah")'
```